# Adding text for visually challanged people

Tags: html, css, wai-aria, screen-readers

In a web application when the user enters data and tabs out, I'm giving a tick mark to the right of control indicating that the required field validation is successful.  If the user tabs to another control without entering data, I'm showing a cross mark.

The styles I'm using are:

for tick

```
input-valid::after {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1em;
    content: "\2714";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #438D5B;
}
```

for cross

```
input-invalid::after {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1em;
    content: "\2716";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #D60036; 
}
```

But for visually challenged people, seeing this tick or cross is a problem. So, I want to read out text "Validation successful" whenever validation is successful.  How can I do it?  Can I do it via CSS itself, so that I can apply the change to the entire application by making it at one place?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you right, you want to add a label that's readable by screen readers.

For that we have the ARIA standard, which is a set of attributes that you can add to HTML elements that communicate role, state and property semantics to assistive technologies via the accessibility APIs implemented in browsers.

I don't have much info on this since I've never actually used it myself, but I can provide you some links so you can read about it, hope it helps. Also, as far as I know you can add this with JavaScript so you don't have to make a lot of changes on your application.

http://html5doctor.com/using-aria-in-html/
http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/

Comment: yes, i understand we need to use ARIA labels, but sure which one and how...

Comment: @user1447718 Well, as I said, I've never really used it, so I can't give a straight answer, but here's a guide on aria lables with examples on how to use them, hope it helps you more. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/aria-labels-and-relationships)